# Non-self-mapping automorphism implies abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(G)$. If $\sigma^2=1$ and $x^{\sigma}\neq x$ for $1\neq x\in G$, show that if $G$ is finite, it must be abelian.

There's a hint to show that the set $\{x^{-1}x^{\sigma}\mid x\in G\}$ is the whole group $G$. I have already proved this hint ($x^{-1}x^{\sigma} = y^{-1}y^{\sigma}\rightarrow (xy^{-1})^{\sigma} = xy^{-1}\rightarrow x=y$ since $x^{\sigma}=x$ only for $x=1$), but I could not use it to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\in G$ we have $(x^{-1}x^\sigma)^\sigma=(x^{-1})^\sigma x=(x^{-1}x^\sigma)^{-1}$, but $x^{-1}x^\sigma$ runs over $G$ as $x$ does, so for each $x\in G$ we have $x^\sigma=x^{-1}$. Thus, for any $x,y\in G$ we have

$$(xy)^\sigma=x^\sigma y^\sigma=x^{-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}=(yx)^\sigma$$

and hence $xy=yx$.

Comment: How does it follow that every non-identity element of $G$ is of order $2$? I thought we need $x=x^{-1}$ for that.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry: my mind went walkabout. What I had was silly, but it should be okay now.

Comment: That's okay, thanks!

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!